# Setting width on calculated properties has no effect on output

Tags: powershell

I have the following simple PowerShell script:

```
get-process |
  format-table name, @{name='VM(MB)';width=50000;expression={$_.VM};alignment='right'}
```

However, when I was experimenting with the width parameter, I found that it does not have any effect on onscreen output. No matter what value I set it to, 5 or 50000 or any value in between, the result is exactly the same.

Am I missing something here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to find something more authoritative but it appears the issue is that the width is not honored when it is not specified on *leading* properties in the output set. If you do one of the following you get the requested adjustments.

- remove `name`

  ```
  get-process | format-table @{name='VM(MB)';width=50;expression={$_.VM};alignment='right'}
  ```
- set the width of `name`

  ```
  get-process | format-table @{name='Name (Yo)';width=40;expression={$_.Name};alignment='left'},@{name='VM(MB)';width=50;expression={$_.VM};alignment='right'}
  ```
- change property order

  ```
  get-process | format-table @{name='VM(MB)';width=50;expression={$_.VM};alignment='right'}, name
  ```

It looks like it is not sure what to do when your first properties do not have widths set so it performs its default formatting operations.

Testing was done on PSv5. Other versions might work differently.

Comment: Thanks. It appears so. However, it also seems that the width for the leading property would apply to all other properties except those with explicitly set width.

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue and need some help, the last column FullName is being truncated, here's the command dirs = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $path | Format-Table -AutoSize -HideTableHeaders -Property @{n='Mode';e={$_.Mode};width=50}, @{n='LastWriteTime';e={$_.LastWriteTime};width=50}, @{n='Length';e={$_.Length};width=50}, @{n='Name';e={$_.FullName -replace '^.:\\[^\\]*\\(.*)','$1'};width=10000} | Out-String.    Using -Wrap will fix the truncation issue but then the path is broken up over multiple lines, which is also undesirable